# Cannot find SerialAddress class in Apache Mina 2.0.2

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml, apache-mina

I added the below dependencies in my project POM file and the `SerialAddress` class is no where to be found from the downloaded `mina-core.2.0.2.jar`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

the package `org.apache.mina.transport.serial` doesnt even exist. Please advice me on the correct Dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this class is not part of mina-core. Some exploration lead to the existence of [Apache Mina Serial Communication Support](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mina/mina-transport-serial/2.0.2).

So I guess you would want to add the dependency for mina-transport-serial.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-transport-serial</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```